# not clear with stripslash() functionality

Tags: php

I am new in PHP world. While going through couple of functions i came across stripslash()
I am not clear about it's benefit. Gone through couple of google link but still it's benefit is not clear.

```
<?php
    $array=array("a"=>"0","b"=>"1","c"=>"2");
    print_r ($array);
    print "\n";

    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
            print "Before stripslash : $value\n";
            stripslashes($value);
            print "After stripslash : $value\n";
    }
    print_r ($array);
?>
```

Output:

Array
(
    [a] => 0
    [b] => 1
    [c] => 2
)

Before stripslash : 0
After stripslash : 0
Before stripslash : 1
After stripslash : 1
Before stripslash : 2
After stripslash : 2

Array
(
    [a] => 0
    [b] => 1
    [c] => 2
)

Comment: Do you understand English? **strip** (remove/delete) **slashes** (/).

Comment: Check out the examples in the manual: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: @Sawny: It doesn't remove forward slashes. Check out the manual for more info on the function.

Comment: Got confused with the statement in the document "stripslashes — Un-quotes a quoted string".. Thought it will remove quote marks. Anyway I made changes in the array mentioned above                 $array=array("a"=>"\'0","b"=>"\\1","c"=>"\\2");                    now the output is : Array
(
    [a] => \'0
    [b] => \1
    [c] => \2
)

arrayBefore stripslash : \'0
After stripslash : \'0
Before stripslash : \1
After stripslash : \1
Before stripslash : \2
After stripslash : \2
ARRAY : Array
Array
(
    [a] => \'0
    [b] => \1
    [c] => \2
) Where is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/strip_slashes) clearly explain. The first example from that page:

```
<?php
    $str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

    // Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
    echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

the php function addslashes puts a backslash character in front of any other character that my interfere with an SQL query.  stripslashes reverses this by removing the backslash characters

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of this function is to strip the slashes off of a string

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

simple source [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: I made changes in the array mentioned above $array=array("a"=>"\'0","b"=>"\\1","c"=>"\\2"); now the output is : Array ( [a] => \'0 [b] => \1 [c] => \2 ) arrayBefore stripslash : \'0 After stripslash : \'0 Before stripslash : \1 After stripslash : \1 Before stripslash : \2 After stripslash : \2 ARRAY : Array Array ( [a] => \'0 [b] => \1 [c] => \2 ) Where is the difference?